# Can I write Ubuntu phone applications in C/C++?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

As a console game programmer, I have lots of code already written in C++ that I'd like to port to the Ubuntu phone. I see the the QT-based environment lets you "extend" QT with C++, but I really just want to write programs native in C++. Is that possible? Is there some documentation on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible, QML is the language used to define an interface and how it reacts to certain things, JavaScript is used to extend this slightly, giving you the tools to write some pretty cool things, but to harness the full power or Ubuntu you will NEED to write C++

Here is a helpful link

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=41078787

I haven't really found any real, usable documentation as yet, remember the touch platform is still rather young.