# What are limitations of ubuntu phone comparing to ubuntu desktop?

Tags: command-line, compatibility, phone

All the reviews for ubuntu phone seems to be targeted for *phone users* (how is the touch, gestures, scopes, etc). I am however, interested to know about this new OS as an *ubuntu users*.

I was wondering if I buy an ubuntu phone, what would I miss when comparing to desktop version. In particular, I am curios to know about:

1. Is there a fully functional terminal?
2. Is it possible to use `apt-get` for installing packages?
3. Can I install desktop environments?
4. Can I compile an arbitrary C++ program? I am not talking about a QT GUI application, but simple command line executable.
5. Python? Lua? R? Programming languages in general?

In short, I would like to know as an ubuntu user, what are the major limitations of the phone operating system.

Comment: Too many questions in 1 topic where msot of them are already answered on Ask Ubuntu. Examples: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361459/can-i-write-ubuntu-phone-applications-in-c-c  http://askubuntu.com/questions/314329/is-it-possible-to-use-python-with-the-ubuntu-sdk http://askubuntu.com/questions/536333/ubuntu-touch-using-apt-get http://askubuntu.com/questions/417891/ubuntu-touch-apt-get

Comment: @Rinzwind, Thank you for the links. I did not consider using ubuntu *touch* in my search query to find out about my questions. Actually, I did not know they are the same product. My bad! But my general question is what I have written in the last paragraph and bullet points are just examples of it. Do you think it is better if I ask a general question about limitations of ubuntu phone and change it to a community wiki?

Comment: Naa I would advice to ask them all separately but it might be too soon for some. Look at python: bindings for it have been added not long ago. You can use C+ in terminal but how limited it is?! No idea. Terminal looks like a BusyBox instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what told to be the fact:

Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu Phone) uses the Qt 5-based touch user interface and various software frameworks originally developed for Maemo and MeeGo such as oFono as telephony stack, accounts-sso for single sign-on, and Maliit for input. Utilizing libhybris the system can often be used with Linux kernels used in Android, which makes it easily ported to most recent Android smartphones.

Ubuntu Phone OS utilizes the same core technologies as the Ubuntu Desktop, so applications designed for the latter platform run on the former and vice versa. Additionally, Ubuntu Desktop components come with the Ubuntu Touch system; allowing Ubuntu Touch devices to provide a full desktop experience when connected to an external monitor. Ubuntu Touch devices can be equipped with a full Ubuntu session and may change into a full desktop operating system when plugged into a docking station. If plugged the device can use all the features of Ubuntu and user can perform office work or even play ARM-ready games on such device.